# How to convert date to ISO format in Python With the Z at the end?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-datetime

How to convert date to ISO format in Python With the Z at the end?

The date is:

```
2020-11-01 01:11:39
```

How can I convert it to:

```
2020-11-01T01:11:39Z
```

?

Please help me.

Edit:
[How do I parse an ISO 8601-formatted date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127803/how-do-i-parse-an-iso-8601-formatted-date) doesn't answer my question because I am trying to **CONVERT** normal dates to ISO date.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I parse an ISO 8601-formatted date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127803/how-do-i-parse-an-iso-8601-formatted-date)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are starting out with a `datetime` object, you could use the `strftime()` function here:

```
from datetime import datetime
now = datetime.now()
dt_out = now.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ")
print(dt_out)  # 2021-03-07T07:39:22Z
```

Comment: Is it the correct way to convert it to ISO time? Or any consequences any where?

Comment: Are you looking to _view_ you data in the format you mentioned, or are you instead looking to do some math/operation with it?  If the former, then my answer is appropriate.

Comment: I want to show it to the user. Don't ask me why I chose a format like this, all I can tell is that I am building a whois server, and I believe I am almost done with it

Comment: Then using `strftime()` as I have done above should be fine.  There might be some canned shortcut if you want something common, like ISO time, but otherwise what I gave above is valid.

Comment: And I do not store it in anywhere.

Comment: `Z` means that the datetime object you want to format to string refers to UTC - in your example, it is a naive datetime object, which doesn't refer to any time zone (Python just assumes local time by default). Attaching a `Z` in `strftime` can thus be misleading.